# Is it actually possible to use implicit flow to get the access_token in Javascript?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Once I redirect a user to https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token I lose control since my Javascript cannot run on someone elses page. So how can I grab the URL after instagram redirects them? (I am using window.location.replace for the redirect)

To clarify I am using no webservers at all.

Comment: You do realise that you shouldn't *literally* redirect to that URL, right? You're supposed to replace `CLIENT-ID` and `REDIRECT-URI` by the values that are appropriate for your scenario. Given that you control the value that gets used for `REDIRECT-URI`, I don't understand the question, I don't understand why you'd need to grab anything.

Comment: Yes, I replace them. Once they login with instagram they are redirected to `REDIRECT-URI` but with the authentication code added to the end of the url (http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN) I then need to grab this URL but, since there I am trying to do this without a webserver I don't own `REDIRECT-URI` so can't execute my Javascript on it. Its explained [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

Comment: If you could intercept the `ACCESS-TOKEN` when the `REDIRECT-URI` is something you don't own, that would be a major security flaw. You need to set up a web server. It doesn't need to cost anything, if that's your concern.

Comment: On the page I linked this method was supposedly for when you had no webservers though. `If you are building an app that does not have a server component `

Comment: That quote looks like it's directed at applications built from static HTML & JS (your quote is followed by "(a purely javascript app, for instance)"). That is, there is no server-side logic. But I should have been more specific. If you have control over the *browser*, you can also obtain the token. That's something you might use if you've got an app that gets installed on user devices, and that app uses a web browser widget, perhaps they mean to include that as well. But I don't see anything in your question to indicate that you're doing anything like that.

Comment: No, I think I will have to use a web server. Thank you for the help.